# NavigationItem TitleView wrong position after Push Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a `ChatViewController`, I set it in the `navigationItem.titleView` `UIView`, which contains the `UIImageView`. I install the image for UIImageView in `viewWillAppear`, it all works well. But when I open the `ChatViewController` by clicking on the Notification button, `UIImageView` has a picture when it's in the right corner. I tried various options, but they helped me. Please tell me how can I solve this? Thank you.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ChatGeneralManager.shared.enterChatViewController()
        super.chatItemsDecorator = ChatItemsDecorator()
        // Settings
        setupSettings()
        // UI 
        addProfileImageView()
    }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        setupConversationImage()
    }

private func addProfileImageView() {
    guard friendImageView == nil else { return }
    let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35))
    friendImageView = UIImageView()
    friendImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 35 / 2
    friendImageView.frame = titleView.bounds
    friendImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    titleView.addSubview(friendImageView)

    friendImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    friendImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    navigationItem.titleView = titleView
}
```

[image]

This is how TitleView looks when I switch to Push Notification, of course when the screen is fully opened, then it is in the center. Of course there is an option to set the image in viewDidAppear, but there it will be noticeable that TitleView is empty at the beginning. And it is very interesting, why when at simple opening works well, and when he presses push notification that is such a disadvantage. While there and there, to open ChatViewController, this function

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(chatViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting it on "viewDidLayoutSubviews()" ?

Comment: @unniverzal No, I tried only in viewWillLayoutSubviews, now I will try to do so

Comment: @unniverzal No, unfortunately it did not help me